# How do you disable bluetooth module on apple keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

i have just bought the apple keyboard but the bluetooth gives me a headache. I want to disable the bluetooth module on the apple keyboard... does anyone know how to do this? Let me be accurate here on what i'm asking, I want to disable the bluetooth module on the keyboard, NOT on the machine.

Comment: Just plug it in.

Comment: Yes, i know how to plug in a keyboard thanks :). I'm specifically trying to disable the bluetooth on internally so that it's inactive. Anyone else have any ideas at all?

Comment: Plugging it in disables bluetooth

Comment: no it does not switch it off sadly. it's still active but not working. So the effect is less but not gone :(. Sadly. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If you want a keyboard that you can turn off Bluetooth, have a look at the [Keychron K8](https://www.keychron.com/pages/keychron-k8-wireless-mechanical-keyboard)  I use it wirelessly, but there is a switch on the side to completely turn off BT.  It's mechanical and a bit noisy, but I much prefer the mechanical feel (learned to type on IBM buckling spring keys) and I love that it's both wired and wireless.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, might try it another time but i've already purchased this keyboard so it's either lose some money by selling it and buying another or finding a way to turn off the BT. I really like the speed of the apple keyboard so i'm hoping to find a solution tnx.

Comment: If you plug your keyboard and disable the ***Mac's*** BT, you might get what you want. Maybe the problem actually comes from the Mac.